# The Requested Service cannot be activated WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

I have a wcf service(REST) with `webHttpBinding`,I first configured it for HTTP and hosted in local IIS it was working great there, Now i moved it to my testing server with Https ,Changed the security mode to transport but now i am getting an exception which says service cannot be activated.IIS didnt log anything

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Configuration is like this

```
 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBinding_StatusReportService"
      closeTimeout="10:10:00" openTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:10:00"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

  <endpoint address="https://...../Services/StatusReportingService.svc"
   behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding"
   bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_StatusReportService"
   contract="ServiceReference1.StatusReportService"
   name="WebHttpBinding_StatusReportService" />

   <behavior name="webEndpoint">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
```

What might be the reason for this

Comment: When ever I get this error, the first place I look is the Event Viewer Windows log, to see if any error was logged there.  In my experience, it always has been and it's always enabled me to quickly diagnose and fix the issue.

Comment: Is the above configuration on client or server?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with adding a certificate and also change the SSL settings in IIS.

The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx captures all the steps.

Comment: <bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
<binding>
<security mode="Transport"/>
</binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings> And <services>
<service name="WcfService13.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="svcBehavior">
<endpoint name="" binding="webHttpBinding" address="" contract="WcfService13.IService1" />
</service>
</services> .Please give a try with this.Take care to specify ur  contract.